# Save/update multiple rows in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm currently working on saving a user social media posts in my app.  The basic idea is to check if the post exists if it does update the data or if not create a new row.  Right now I'm looping through all of the post that I receive from the social platform so potentially I'm looping through 3,000 and adding them to the database.

Is there a way that I could rewrite this to save all the items at once, which hopefully would speed up the save method?

```
   post_data.each do |post_data_details|
      post_instance = Post::Tumblr.
                      where(platform_id: platform_id).
                      where("data ->> 'id' = ?", post_data_details["id"].to_s).
                      first_or_initialize

      exisiting_data = post_instance.data
      new_data = exisiting_data.merge! post_data_details.to_hash
      post_instance.data = new_data

      post_instance.refreshed_at = date
      post_instance.save!
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to run such long-running jobs via sidekiq or other background jobs solution.

You can also use single ActiveRecord transaction.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

But keep in mind, that if one of records will be invalid - whole trasaction will be rollbacked.